# how to direct the application using Facebook login to the main view of the application

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-ios-sdk

can anybody help e with the login screen?

i have designed a mobile application that uses Facebook login, I've got all of that working but having issue to view the main screen.

The Facebook button logs in a user and logs them out which i wanted, but the Facebook button does not take the user to the main screen how do i do that?

i have taken screen shot of the application, the two screen shot show a user can log in and log out and the third screen shot is the home page of an application, once the user have logged in, i want the application to take the user onto the main page.

the following is the code for Facebook button

```
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import "FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h"

@interface LoginViewController ()

@end

@implementation LoginViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    FBSDKLoginButton *loginButton = [[FBSDKLoginButton alloc] init];
    loginButton.center = self.view.center;
    [self.view addSubview:loginButton];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}


 @end
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Facebook button you can use custom button and add functionality 
you can use following code

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
 [super viewDidLoad];



// Add a custom login button to your app
  UIButton *myLoginButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
  myLoginButton.backgroundColor=[UIColor darkGrayColor];
  myLoginButton.frame=CGRectMake(0,0,180,40);
  myLoginButton.center = self.view.center;
  [myLoginButton setTitle: @"My Login Button" forState: UIControlStateNormal];

  // Handle clicks on the button
  [myLoginButton 
    addTarget:self 
    action:@selector(loginButtonClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

  // Add the button to the view
  [self.view addSubview:myLoginButton];
}

// Once the button is clicked, show the login dialog
-(void)loginButtonClicked
{
  FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
  [login
    logInWithReadPermissions: @[@"public_profile"]
          fromViewController:self
                     handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
    if (error) { 
      NSLog(@"Process error");
    } else if (result.isCancelled) {
      NSLog(@"Cancelled");
    } else {
```

> ```
>       // here you can push or present controller
> ```

```
      NSLog(@"Logged in");
    }
  }];
}
```

@end

Answer (score 0):

You can use FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate for catching event when user is loged in Facebook.

```
- (void) loginButton:(FBSDKLoginButton *)loginButton didCompleteWithResult: (FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *)result error:(NSError *)error { 
if (result) {
    [self perfromSegueWithIdentifier:@"YourSegueIdentifier" sender:self];
}}
```

I think, this can help you.